# Accessing AWS Secret Manager With Assumed Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using the following to authenticate my aws-sdk (v3) requests in my React app:

```js
const options = {
      region: 'us-east-1',
      credentials: fromCognitoIdentityPool({
            identityPoolId: "us-east-1:*****",
            clientConfig: {
                  region: import.meta.env.VITE_AWS_REGION,
            },
      })
};
export const unAuthedCognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(options);
export const secretsManagerClient = new SecretsManagerClient(options);
```

All the cognito client functions seems to work.

For some reason, the code relates to the secrets manager is not working.Here is the error I am getting:

`User: arn:aws:sts::****:assumed-role/for-cognito-access/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: dev/App because no session policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action`

Here is the permissions policy:

```json
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
            {
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                        "cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity",
                        "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
                        "secretsmanager:*"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                        "*"
                  ]
            }
      ]
}
```

As you can see, I've included secretsmanager:* thinking it should solve this issue, but it didn't.

How can I grant the assumed role access to the secrets manager?

Comment: The permission you shared is a resource policy attached to the secret or iam policy attached to the role?

Comment: iam policy attached to the role

Comment: Can you try `fromTemporaryCredentials` from @aws-sdk/credential-providers, instead of `fromCognitoIdentityPool`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either